# Power BI - Data Modeling

Tags: report, powerbi, star-schema, fact-table

I recently came across the star schema and its advantages. I am new to Power BI and Database modeling.

I am making a Power BI Report.

I planned hours for all my members in my team for each Project and thus calculated the hours spent with their hourly rate and got the budget for every Project for the year. This is my first table. I have EmployeeName, Hours, Date, ProjectName, TotalCost

I get the monthly timesheet from SAP after they include their hours. The fields are the same. EMployeeNAme, PostingDate, Hours, Cost, ProjectName.

Now, I need to make a report where I see the difference between what was planned and what I get from my Timesheet. And how much budget is remaining for the next two months.

I should be able to filter this for each employee, each project and between any month.

I do not know what do I make Fact Table and what will be my Dimensions Table.

How do I use StarSchema in this?

Comment: Could you please try to improve readability of your question? Some new lines would make it easier to digest.

Comment: Table 1: Fields: Employee Name, Project, Posting Date, Total Hrs, Total Cost(this I get it from SAP every month)
Table 2: Fields: Employee Name, Project, Date, Total Hrs, Total Cost (for each month I planned in the beginning of the year, which is forecast, the total cost gives me budget for the whole year)
Report: Budget Actual Vs Forecast, remaining budget for each project, for each employee, for each month.

Comment: Euhm how does this make the question more readable?

Comment: I planned budget for the whole year for my employees, with their hours allocated for each project. So I have my first table, which has:

EmployeeName, Date, Hrs, ProjectName, Total Budget(based on per day rate)

I get my table 2 from timesheet, which has same fields, with the hours they actually worked on that project.

I need to compare the two tables, for each project what was the forecast, with the actuals vs planned. With the help of a slicer, I should be able to see this for each employee, per month, per Project. 
LIne breaks are not supported in comments?

Comment: Please read what I am telling you. Your question is not readable because it lacks formatting. Put in some new lines and paragraphs. Also, do not post additional information in comments but edit the question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I edited my question now.

Comment: @Light - you are asking us to do the entire dimensional modeling work for you. A more reasonable approach is: 1) Read a good book on dimensional modeling/star schema design. 2) Try to design your first star schema yourself. 3) Post a new question with the image of your design and ask stack overflow folks for feedback/suggestions how to improve or fix it. You will get much better results.